# When running WKWebView with PageViewController, the swipe does not work

Tags: ios, c, wkwebview, uipageviewcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D7CJ.jpg)

(Please refer to the image above.)

I want to create and swipe WKWebView for each of the three Xib files.
However, when WKWebView is running, the swipe is not working, and when the swipe is enabled, the WKWebView is not running.

I think the reason is addSubView.
The implementation method was to run XIB's WebView and add RootView's XIB.(ex. [self.rootview addSubView:A(xib).view]) As a result, webview will run but will not be swiped.

However, without addSubView, WKWebView will not run, but the swipe will work. What are the possible ways to solve this?